# ASMCA(ASM Configuration Assistant) GUI is not rendering properly

Tags: oracle, rac, oracle-asm

[image: ASMCA Oracle Utility]

Hi Gurus,

While running **ASMCA utility on OEL 7.5**, Oracle is not able to render the GUI of the tool. I clicked on exit button and next screen comes as a vertical line (Screen attached above).No option there to expand the window.

Have ever anyone come across this type of issue? Please let me know if you have solution for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Prabhakar

Comment: No, I have never come accross this type of issue. It is because I never install GUI on a server because it is a waste of resources. An X server (for example Xming on Windows) and an SSH client (PuTTY) with X11 forwarding does wonders.

Comment: Thanks Balazs. This happens because of color display setting of linux GNOME desktop. I also used Xming to complete the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of color display setting of Linux GNOME desktop. I used Xming Software on windows for remote installation.It worked.

Comment: Could you elaborate?  This sounds very similar to a still unresolved issue I have with the OUI, using ssh to connect to a vm from an Ubuntu laptop.

Comment: @EdStevens I am not sure why it's not working on Linux machine(installed on VM). Though OUI passed prerequisites for display, still it is partially not able to render the UI. Please share if you have something more about this. I have just updated the workaround. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: I have nothing to add. I was asking _you_ to elaborate on your statement "This happens because of color display setting of Linux GNOME desktop. " I was hoping what you found to make "it worked" would also solve my problem.  I don't see where you " updated the workaround.".